# usar o ip do usuario como proxy para fazer request

Tags: php, libcurl, http-request, request, guzzle

Estou desenvolvendo um site usando o guzzle e queria se tem como usar o ip e a porta que o usuario acessa o site como proxy na hora da requisição ja tentei esses codigos e n foi

```
<?php
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$porta = getenv("REMOTE_PORT");
$ip2 = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
require '/php.php';
$body = request("http://www.paodeacucar.com/", $ref, 'GET', ['proxy' => 'http://' . $ip . ':' . $porta]);
echo $body;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso não é possível, por uma razão óbvia. Se isso fosse possível a pratica de IP-Spoofing seria extremamente mais fácil, afinal você conseguiria se passar por qualquer IP (e ainda conseguir obter a resposta em nome desse IP).

A única forma disso funcionar é se o cliente aceitar essas conexões, interpretar o pedido e devolver a resposta para o seu servidor, o que ele nunca irá fazer por padrão. *Afinal, ele não é um proxy.*

**As alternativas, que consigo pensar agora, são:**

- Executar o código no navegador via Javascript/WASM, *supondo que o corpo da resposta seja significante*. Entretanto, é preciso que o seu site esteja autorizado pelo CORS, dependendo do caso. Como essa requisição parte do cliente o IP dele será usado.
- Executar isto fora do contexto do navegador, como um aplicativo ou executável. Neste caso você está no lado do cliente, daí você poderá se comunicar usando o IP do usuário, sem qualquer restrição do navegador.

Comment: e como fazia via php para fazer essa pergunta e caso ele altorise usar o ip dele como proxy ? como seria feito essa conexao

Comment: @CyberHacker como de qualquer outra forma. Para uso comuns (HTTP) existe o cURL, que tem o `CURLOPT_PROXY` (https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXY.html).